# Does this function have a Fourier Series representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $$g(x)=\cos(x^5)+\sin(x^2)$$
If we were to have a Fourier Series representation of this function $$g(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n\cos(n\omega_ot)+b_n\sin(n\omega_ot)\right)$$ The question is: Which of its coefficients would be zero?

When I graph this in Desmos, I seem to get a non-periodic function and Symbolab seems to agree with my assumption. We are not given a period or a 'window' in the question either but the solution suggests that since $g(x)$ is an even function $b_n=0$ and $a_n$ can have a non-zero value. How can we even have a Fourier Series representation if the function does not have a period or a given 'window'?

(This is not a homework or a quiz question.).

Comment: You're right that without being given a window, no conclusion can be drawn about the Fourier coefficients. Perhaps the context of the question implicitly assumed something of the form $[-L,L]$ so check your references

Comment: The fact that you are **given** the Fourier series in terms of $\omega_0$, it means that the period of $g(x)$ is $2\pi/\omega_0$

Comment: If the window is $[-L,L]$, then we will have $b_n = 0$. Otherwise there's little that can be said about it. This function does have a Fourier transform on $(-\infty,\infty)$, although there's probably not a closed form.

Comment: The function is not periodic, so it does not have a Fourier series; the question of what coefficients _would_ vanish if it did have a Fourier series is meaningless